# CSS hover property alternative for IE

Tags: javascript, css

CSS Hover property doesn't seem to work in IE but works fine in Firefox. So what can be the workaround for the following code for IE?

```
a#aUpdateZip:hover , a#aCancelZip:hover { 
    text-decoration:underline; 
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
}
```

Comment: lol hover totally works in IE, man. There must be some other mistake in your code... what is this selector supposed to do? "a#aUpdateZip:hover

Comment: So you're referring to IE6 only, right?

Comment: did you try adding a display: block; ?

Comment: some question about hover in IE6 [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441314/ie6-css-hover-issues-with-menu) but really, who uses ie6 today?

Comment: @Gatekeeper lot of people use IE6.....

Comment: @Side well those people shouldn't be allowed to go online :-D IE6 is so bad... is there any reason not to upgrade to some newer version? Its like you were watching 30 years old tv and were complaining about picture quality :-)

Comment: @Romit You seem to be using `id`s as if they were `class`es. You are not supposed to have more than a single item with the same id (in the same page).

Comment: @side: Less then 10% of internet users are on ie6 now, more than half of which are from China. This is such a small percentage of people, especially if not targeting China, that it is not worth supporting IE6. Microsoft themselves are trying to kill it: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: @gatekeeper , i am using IE7..

Comment: @ANeves .. lol..what are u interpreting of the code there.. i am not at all using elements with the same id..the code refers to two anchor tags having different ids..

Comment: @RichardS ..What answers are u talking about..

Comment: @Romit he is talking about answers to your other 11 questions.. you havent accepted a single answer yet that is just rude :-) as for IE7, there should not be any problem with hover...

Comment: @Gatekeeper..i actually give the feedback Y or N of whether a post was useful or not..Is there anything else, i need to do..

Comment: @Romit you should accept answer that solved your problem by clicking on "check" icon beneath answer rating(up and down arrows). That gives a lot more points to user who posted that answer and shows him that you actually used this solution...

Comment: @GateKeeper Then, may be text-decoration:underline; is not working in IE..any alternatives for IE?

Comment: @Romit That works too :-D i think you have some mistake in your css selectors maybe it would be better if you make some demo on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Romit it just seemed like you were defining generic styles for "buttons" using `id`s. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use JQuery? Add some nice hover effects? For example...

```
    $("#aUpdate").hover(function () 
    {
        $(this).stop().animate({"color": "#000000"}, "medium")
    }, 
    function () 
    {
        $(this).stop().animate({"color": "#ffffff"}, "fast")
    });
```

Comment: Great way to welcome someone to the community by straight away negativly repping answers...

Comment: he asked help for css, not jquery, he will never learn from this, dont understand people is something not working in the css they immediately start grabbing jquery

Comment: The title of this question actually says "Alternative".

Comment: @Graeme Leighfield One of the original tags is `Javascript`. If not for that, I would fully second @Side 's opinion. Otherwise, Javascript is not a proper alternative for CSS2. A good example of this bad practice is people using Javascript to do hover-menus á la Suckerfish.

Comment: But other than that, you should not be ashamed or afraid of negative rep. One upvote will clean it all out for you. :)